ESP32-cam and TB6612 motor driver : how to slow down motor speed?
I'm building a small robot with the following components:

2 x 3.7V Lipo batteries (series) -> 7.4V
TB6612 motor driver
2x 6V DC motors
ESP32-CAM with antenna as microcontroller (AI Thinker)

I'd like to reduce the default speed of the motors.
As pins 12, 13, 14 and 15 are used by the 2 motors, I'm essentially left with pin 16 for the PWMA and PWMB. So I connected these 2 cables to this pin.
Here are the variables I use for this :
#define MOTOR_PWR 16
const int motorSpeed = 30;

My problem is as follows:
As soon as I add the line (to the setup function)
pinMode(MOTOR_PWR, OUTPUT);

and upload the code, the webserver doesn't start correctly anymore and send this message :
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1448
load:0x40078000,len:14844
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:4
load:0x40080404,len:3356
entry 0x4008059c
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46
over and over...

Does anyone know of a way to manage the speed of motors connected to a TB6612 module (probably the same for the L298N module)?

I finally found the solution. Pin 16 is supposed to be the most usable of the ESP32 cam's pins. However, can't explain why, but in this case, here are the pins I used to make it work:

AN1: 2
AN2 : 14
BN1 : 15
BN2 : 13
PWMA and PWNB : 12

